# How to put the image close to the text in list-style-image?

Tags: html, css

So recently I'm trying to create a list-style-image code it worked but the images are on the far left. Anything to help me here? or is the picture is to big?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
 list-style-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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") ;
 }
ul.a {
  list-style-position: outside;
}

ul.b {
  list-style-position: inside;
}

ol { list-style-image: url('https://i.redd.it/0839542hglz71.jpg') 7px 7px ;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1> <center> List style image property </center> </h1>

<ul>
<center> <li> one </li> </center>
<center> <li> two </li> </center>
<center> <li> three </li> </center>
</ul>
<ol>
<center> <li> one </li> </center>
<center> <li> two </li> </center>
<center> <li> three </li> </center>
</ol>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: The first think to do is to validate your code: https://validator.w3.org/. It's invalid

Comment: First of `<center>` is long time deprecated, secondly `<center>` is not a valid child of `<ul>` or `<ol>`

Comment: Those centers are making the content of the lis center - which the browser is obligingly doing even though the centers are not only deprecated but incorrectly placed as children of the ul/ol. So of course there's lots of space. Start by getting rid of the centers and watch the images and text come together. Then start to work on vertical positioning and sizing (depending on what you want).

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code and instead on marker image use `pseudo elements`, see Code Snippet, for more details see comments in code:

```css
ul, ol {
  list-style: none; /* remove default markers */
  padding-left: 0; /* remove default left padding (old place of markers) */
}

ul li,
ol li {
  display: flex; /* make li element flex */
  align-items: center; /* center content */
  gap: 1rem; /* gap between marker and content */
}

ul li:before,
ol li:before {
  content: '';
  width: 2rem; /* width of marker */
  aspect-ratio: 1/1; /* make it square (or any other aspect ratio) */
  background-size: contain; /* scale background image */
  background-position: center; /* center background image */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

ul li:before {
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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");
}


ol li:before {
  background-image: url('https://i.redd.it/0839542hglz71.jpg');
}
```

```html
<p>UL list:</p>
<ul>
  <li> one </li>
  <li> two </li>
  <li> three </li>
</ul>

<p>OL list:</p>
<ol>
  <li> one </li>
  <li> two </li>
  <li> three </li>
</ol>
```